# Heroku fails to find class in jar file

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm deploying a jar file to Heroku, but Heroku constantly complains of being unable to find a class file (in a dependency jar). I've already included the class in my jar and it runs flawlessly when run locally, but when I run it on Heroku, it spits out the error:

```
2016-06-13T06:04:30.743345+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
2016-06-13T06:04:30.743349+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
2016-06-13T06:04:30.744920+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
2016-06-13T06:04:30.744922+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
2016-06-13T06:04:30.744923+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
2016-06-13T06:04:30.744926+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
2016-06-13T06:04:30.744927+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
2016-06-13T06:04:30.745502+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2016-06-13T06:04:30.745510+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 7 more
2016-06-13T06:04:31.375413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-06-13T06:04:31.774220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-13T06:04:31.789553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've included the Maven dependency along with the actual jar in my jar file. Does Heroku require the dependency to be located somewhere else before being deployed? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Does anyone know for certain where Heroku checks for class files?

Comment: have you created fat-jar? [single jar with all your dependencies in it]

Comment: How do you run the application locally? How do you assemble the application?

Comment: Please show us your `Procfile` too

Answer (score 0):

If its a springboot app make sure your pom  tag looks like this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: "looks like this" sounds rather vague, could you please be more specific?

Comment: here goal "repackage" creates an executable jar file so running it on heroku wont crash if I am not wrong this is what I added extra before I solved this problem:
`<execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
</execution>`

Also check your Procfile whether your command to run on heroku once the project has been uploaded looks this way:
`web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/<jar_name>.jar`